# Draw continuously gradient line in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I have searched and searched and not found anything that works for me. How can I draw a continuously line with a gradient in cocos2d-iphone? I have tried CCRibbon but then I get gaps, and I have tried to draw multiple aligned lines in the draw method but with different alpha vales, but my draw method does not react to setting the alpha (it is always 100% alpha, see my draw method here under). How can I do this please?

```
- (void)draw {
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glColor4ub(0,255,255,50);
    ccDrawLine( ccp(0 - 5, 0 - 5), ccp(200 - 5, 300 - 5) );
}
```

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is what you need:

```
- (void)draw {
    static GLubyte alpha = 0;
    static int step = 1;

    alpha += step;
    if (alpha == 255 || alpha == 0) {
        step = -step;
    }

    // You gonna need these two lines to use Alpha channel
    glEnable(GL_BLEND); // disabled by default
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glColor4ub(0, 255, 255, alpha);
    ccDrawLine(ccp(0, 0), ccp(200, 300));
}
```

For more information about `GL_BLEND` and `glBlendFunc` you can refer to [OpenGL ES 1.1 Reference](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/).

Answer (score 0):

From the question I'm thinking you want, for example, a thick line that runs from left to right and a gradient that runs from the top of that line to the bottom.  If so, then this is how I did it.  I created a 1 x 6 png image that had a vertical gradient with an alpha built into it.  Then when I wanted to create a line, I would call my drawLine method in my layer.

```
- (void) drawLine: (CGPoint)origin withEnd:(CGPoint)end
{
    CCSprite *wall = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"WallGradient.png"];

    float distance = sqrt(powf(origin.x - end.x, 2) + powf(origin.y - end.y, 2));
    float rotation = (180/M_PI) * acosf((origin.x - end.x) / distance));

    [wall setScaleX:distance];
    [wall setRotation: rotation];
    [wall setPosition: origin];

    [self addChild:wall];
}
```